# Can I set text on a flex Graphics object?

Tags: apache-flex, graphics, datagrid

Is there anyway I can effectively call the equiv. of setText on a Flex Graphics object ?

Specifically I'm using a custom cell renderer to display data in a datagrid. The renderer uses the Graphics object to set the background colour of only a portion of the cell (say the left half) based upon the underlying data. I would like to be able to have text over only that portion of the cell which has the background colour (eg centred within the left half).

I know all the widths (of both the cell itself and the graphics object) but I don't know how I can set text (centred) over the graphics object.

Anyone got any ideas pls?
Tks vm

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that avoids adding UI components:

```
    private function WriteText(text:String, rect:Rectangle):void
    {
        var uit:UITextField = new UITextField();
        uit.text = text;
        uit.width = rect.width;
        var textBitmapData:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(uit);
        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        var x:int = rect.x;
        var y:int = rect.y;
        matrix.tx = x;
        matrix.ty = y;
        graphics.beginBitmapFill(textBitmapData,matrix,false);
        graphics.drawRect(x,y,uit.measuredWidth,uit.measuredHeight);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
```

The idea is to use the UITextField to create a bitmap, that can be used with the graphics object to fill a rectangle.

This is based on a [blog post](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Adding_text_to_flash_display_Graphics_instance-14246.html) by Olga Korokhina at Adobe Developer Connection.

Comment: That's a nice trick, but you will lose font anti aliasing with this.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't draw text programmatically with a Graphics object. What you'll need to do is create one of the Text-like classes (e.g. Label, Text, etc.) and position that appropriately within your cell renderer.

Assuming that you're doing your custom painting in `updateDisplayList`, you'd want to do something like the following:

```
override protected function updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number ):void
{
    super.updateDisplayList( unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight );

    // perform all your custom painting

    var label:Label = new Label();
    label.text = "Some text";

    label.width = widthOfCustomPainting;
    // can also set x- and y-coordinates of label too

    label.setStyle( "textAlign", "center" );

    this.addChild( label );
}
```

This will need some tweaking based on how your item renderer is set up, but it should pretty much be what you need.

Note that my code above does *not* use best practices for custom item renderers. It would be worthwhile to take a look at [this excellent blog post](http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2007/03/thinking_about_item_renderers_1.html) which describes how to properly create item renderers.

Comment: Also, if you want to go crazy, UITextField is the _more native_ text element (or TextField). Either of these you can actually set a background color anyway, so it might serve as the shading part of this problem too.

Comment: Good point, Glenn! You could just use a text field with a specified width and background colour and not even have to worry about custom painting.

Comment: Fantastic - thanks very much it's worked. It may not be the most elegant solution but for now it's fine for me.

I actually had to give my label a name and check to see if a child of that name was already added to 'this'... so ....

if (this.getChildByName(tmpLabel.name) == null){
   this.addChild(tmpLabel);
}

I think this is because of the rendering process (maybe what's in your blog which I will read !).

Tks again.

Comment: Glad to hear everything works! I would definitely recommend the blog post, though. It's written by one of the guys on the Flex team at Adobe so he really understands the internals of Flex.

Answer (score 0):

Polygonal labs comes up with a solution that convert the font to vector curves so that you can draw the text as graphics. [See it here](http://lab.polygonal.de/2009/04/26/goodbye-textfield/). The code has not been published, but you can see some similar projects in the comments.

But you will need to do it in AS instead of MXML or you write you own class for that.

Answer (score 0):

using textformat for uit's defaulttextformat is the solution of my problem...